# Shopware 6 - cache key of logged in storefront user

Tags: caching, shopware6

Is there a way to figure out the full cache key of a logged in frontend user?
The task is to dispay a specific info on the product listing and on the detail page after a customer has bought the product. So we need to clear the specific cache after the customer bought a product.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `CacheInvalidator` and invalidate the cache entries tagged with the product id yourself.

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Cache\CacheInvalidator;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Cache\EntityCacheKeyGenerator;

class CacheInvalidatorService
{
    public function __construct(private readonly CacheInvalidator $cacheInvalidator) 
    {
    }

    public function invalidate(string $productId): void
    {
        $this->cacheInvalidator->invalidate([EntityCacheKeyGenerator::buildProductTag($productId)]);
    }
}
```

This should suffice if you have a generic value that updates after each purchase, like a counter increasing with each purchase or something.

The customer itself has no specific cache key. Otherwise there would be a cache entry for every single customer, essentially contradicting the principle of caching. So if you want to display something entirely customer specific, like if a customer has bought the product before, you can [listen to the specific page load event](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page#adding-data-to-the-storefront), e.g. `ProductPageLoadedEvent`. In the subscriber you can then use the current customer, fetch additional data and add it as extension. With a logged-in customer the http cache should be circumvented by default and the object-cached response, including the product(s) will be part of the aforementioned events.

```php
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onProductPageLoaded',
        ];
    }

    public function onProductPageLoaded(ProductPageLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        // the object that could've previously been cached
        $page = $event->getPage();
        
        $customer = $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getCustomer();
        $product = $page->getProduct();
        
        if (!$customer) {
            return;
        }
        
        // do something with the customer and product
        // ...
        
        // add additional data as extension for use in the template
        $page->addExtension('myExtension', $someExtension);
    }
}
```